# Passing objects to functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, object

I wrote the following code which is working perfectly fine. However what confused me was that when I create a Student object for example 'a', and then I call a member function on it a.calculator(a). Isn't it redundant that I'm passing the same object as an argument when I'm using the dot operator to call the function on the same object. Any explanation would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Semester{
    int credits;
    int gradePoints;
};

class Student{
private:
    string name;
    string major;
    Semester cgpa[8];

public:
    Student();
    Student(string name, string major);
    int calculator(Student &a);
    void enterGrades(Student &a);
};

Student::Student(){
    name = "-";
    major = "Undeclared";
}
Student::Student(string name_, string major_){
    name = name_;
    major = major_;
}

int Student::calculator(Student& a){
    int cgpa = 0;
    int gpa = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        gpa = (a.cgpa[i].credits * a.cgpa[i].gradePoints)/ a.cgpa[i].credits;
        cgpa = cgpa + gpa;
    }
    return cgpa/8;
}

void Student::enterGrades(Student& a){
    int credits;
    int gp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        cout<<"Enter Semester "<<i+1<<" credits: ";
        cin>>credits;
        a.cgpa[i].credits = credits;
        cout<<"Enter Semester "<<i+1<<" grade points: ";
        cin>>gp;
        a.cgpa[i].gradePoints = gp;
    }
}

int main(){
    Student a("Hasan", "CS");
    a.enterGrades(a);
    cout<<"The students CGPA is "<<a.calculator(a)<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Yes it is. You don't need to do that, just use `this`.

Comment: You dont need to pass the same object to the function. You dont even need "this". You just omit the paramter in the calculator definition and use the data members  as is, for ex.:  cgpa[i].credits  instead of  a.cgpa[i].credits

Comment: a member function can work on the class data members of the current instance, which is likely what you want to do. as @SpencerWieczorek suggested, you can first try to remove the `Stutend& a` parameter from all the member functions you defined and replace `a.` with `this->`. Then you can take advantage of the fact that this-> is implicit within a body function when referring to class data members (and meber functions as well), and homit it completely

Comment: @StPiere Using this-> works fine, but when I omit it completely I get the error "invalid types int[int] for array subscript" in the calculator function

Comment: @Hassaan: please paste the line of code that the error message targets

Comment: @StPiere When I change this line "gpa = (a.cgpa[i].credits * a.cgpa[i].gradePoints)/ a.cgpa[i].credits" to the one you suggested "gpa = (cgpa[i].credits * cgpa[i].gradePoints)/ cgpa[i].credits;"

Comment: In your calculator() method your are defining the local cgpa variable and it hides the class cgpa data member - this is bad. I've corrected this for you. here working example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rzDBKXYZjD5xKmo3  . In your example using "this" would have been the better idea , that's why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it redundant that I'm passing the same object as an argument when I'm using the dot operator to call the function on the same object.

If you always call with the same object, then that's redundant yes. However, using a parameter allows you to pass another object than the object of the call.

From another perspective: It is redundant for the function to be a non-static member function since it doesn't use any of the members of `this`.